# SDL 2.0.3 event loop doesn't work

Tags: c++, sdl

I can't make SDL wait for a an event. When I try to the window just briefly flashes on my screen and then disappears, I don't get any errors or anything in my IDE, nothing in the build log either. I looked at lazyfoo and the SDL wiki, but no help. I'm using Code blocks and SDL 2.0.3 Here's what I have so far:

```
while(&event != NULL && !quit)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) > 0)
    {
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            quit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_LEFT:
                        currentSurface = keyPressSurfaces[KEY_PRESS_LEFT];
                        break;
                    case SDLK_UP:
                        currentSurface = keyPressSurfaces[KEY_PRESS_UP];
                        break;
                    case SDLK_RIGHT:
                        currentSurface = keyPressSurfaces[KEY_PRESS_RIGHT];
                        break;
                    case SDLK_DOWN:
                        currentSurface = keyPressSurfaces[KEY_PRESS_DOWN];
                        break;
                    default:
                        currentSurface = keyPressSurfaces[KEY_PRESS_DEFAULT];
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you actually stepped through this with a debugger?

Comment: ...or at least printf-debugging

Comment: can you please add the declaration of event? And `&event != NULL` is useless, you should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

you are polling for an event `SDL_PollEvent`, if you want to wait for an event, you should use `SDL_WaitEvent`

Comment: I got the same result

Answer (score 0):

First, is `quit` false before you enter this loop?

<s>If there are no events to poll, I believe event is `NULL`, causing your program to exit the next time it sees `while(&event != NULL && !quit)`.  If there are no immediate events on startup, you might not ever make it into that loop.</s> **Edit:** Whoops - thought `event` was a pointer:

The `while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))` line will loop through until all pending events have been handled.  The outter `while (!quit)` would then keep your program open even if there are no events to process at the moment.

Comment: `&event` is the address of `event`, it'll never be NULL. The return value of `SDL_PollEvent` will tell if a new event was written to `&event`.

Comment: Ah - oops.  Sorry, I assumed it was a pointer since he was checking it against NULL.  In that case, quit would have to be false, then, right?

Comment: Yes. All that code could also be in a function that is never called. The way the question is asked, it's difficult to answer without a crystal ball.